# How do I only unmarshal into a field if the json bytes field matches a certain type?

Tags: json, go, encoding, types

What I want to do is commented:

```
type foo struct {
  Message string `json:"message"`
}

func bar() {
  //The "message" field contains a bool type which does not 
  //match the equivalent "message" field in foo, a string type
  jsonData := byte[]("{
    \"message\": true
  }")
  var baz foo
  //Because the type of "message" in the json bytes is 
  //bool and not a string, put "" inside baz.Message
  json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &baz) 
}
```

How do I Unmarshal the json byte array, then only populate the particular field if the field matches the type in the json byte array field? And if the field does type does not match the json byte array field type, put in a placeholder value of nil, "" etc. ?

Comment: You can't, not with the standard library and Go's builtin types. The rules for what json types can be unmarshaled into what Go types can be found in the documentation on [Unmarshal](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal). You can however declare a custom type, have that type implement the `json.Unmarshaler` interface, and in that custom implementation you set your own rules.

Comment: The encoding/json package does not support storing a bool into a string.  Perhaps the field should be as a bool instead?  Also, the JSON is not valid.

Comment: The placeholder value you're speaking of is the [zero value](https://tour.golang.org/basics/12); it's already there. You would however more likely (if you used correct JSON) get the error message (check the error Unmarshal returns!) that you cannot unmarshal a boolean to the go type string.

Comment: It really helps to have your syntax right before you go charging into semantics :-) Here's a [Playground runnable version of your code with an error check](https://play.golang.org/p/NWo6koY2q1g); try it out. Then [fix the remaining obvious error and try again](https://play.golang.org/p/xSL9V2lE8Ku). *Now* you're ready to ask a question!

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to handle this, once you [fix your question to something that can be answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59001905/how-do-i-only-unmarshal-into-a-field-if-the-json-bytes-field-matches-a-certain-t#comment104256864_59001905).  The one I like is to unmarshal to a variable of type `interface{}`, which you can then inspect:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type foo struct {
    Message interface{} `json:"message"`
}

func bar() {
    //The "message" field contains a bool type which does not
    //match the equivalent "message" field in foo, a string type
    jsonData := []byte(`{
    "message": true
  }`)
    var baz foo
    //Because the type of "message" in the json bytes is
    //bool and not a string, put "" inside baz.Message
    err := json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &baz)
    fmt.Printf("unmarhal error is: %v\n", err)
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Printf("baz.Message is now: %T = %v\n", baz.Message, baz.Message)
    }
}

func main() {
    bar()
}
```

([Go Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/TckFwgA7gXm))

It should now be fairly obvious how to switch on the type (after decoding) and see if what you got is what you want.  If so, use it.  If not, use your default.  If necessary, decode the incoming json to more-generic Go types first, *then* fill in the specific type you really want to handle.

Answer (score 1):

The `Unmarshaler` interface in the `encoding/json` package allows you to have full control over how the data is decoded into your types.

You only need to implement one method on your type - `UnmarshalJSON(data []byte)`.

In the example below, I've declared a temporary anonymous type in my `UnmarshalJSON` method and decoded the `json` into an empty interface.

I can then type assert the interface into a `string`, and on success I set the `Message` field on my original `Foo` type. We don't need to handle the failure case, since strings in Go have a default value of `""`.

[Here's a working example.](https://play.golang.org/p/f4ZEMRQAw9J)

```
type Foo struct {
    Message string
}

func (this *Foo) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    raw := struct {
        Message interface{} `json:"message"`
    }{}

    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &raw)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if msgString, ok := raw.Message.(string); ok {
        this.Message = msgString
    }

    return nil
}
```